# How to display a linked category name with get_the_category

Tags: categories

I a code snippet with this bit included...

```
$output .= '<li><a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .' ">' . get_the_title() .'</a> ' . get_the_category() .' '.  get_the_time('d M Y') . '</li>';
```

it works great except the `get_the_category` bit

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) for the function to confirm that it outputs what you thing it does? (it doesn't, you want [`get_the_category_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_list/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_the_category()` returns the array of `WP_Term` objects. So,

```
// get all categories objects
$categories = get_the_category();
// get the first category name
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    $category = $categories[0]->name;
}

$output .= '<li><a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() . ' ">';
$output .= get_the_title() . '</a> ';
$output .= $category .' ';
$output .= get_the_time('d M Y') . '</li>';
```